# Appcelerator automated Functional Testing

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

Is there an alternative to Soasta with the enterprise license for automated functional testing? I'm looking for a solution where we can record clicks, gestures and input etc and play it back.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered Amazon Device Farm. You can upload your app (on a real device) and interact with it. Though I am not sure you can also record these sessions and replay them.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin UI Test. Titanium renders native components, so in your application you can write end-to-end test with it. There is a test recorder (only for Visual Studio) and a REPL which you can use to write your actions one by one and to have a look at the components tree. It's everything based on the compiled file so there aren't integration problems. After you can also automate those tests on Xamarin Test in Cloud.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/

https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud/recorder

https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud